Link between integration of differential forms and complex measures
Suppose that $M$ is a compact smooth manifold of dimension $n$. Let $\omega$ be a $n$-form on $M$ (complex-valued in the sense that $\omega_x$ is a complexified alternated $n$-covector for each $x\in M$). One can define the integral for any continuous function $f:M\to \mathbb{C}$
$$
I_\omega(f)= \int_M f\omega.
$$
Is it possible to extend this to functions that are not continuous? In particular, I would like to make sense of $I_\omega(\chi_A)$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of any Borel subset $A$ of $M$. Obviously $\chi_A \omega$ is not continuous, but it seems to me that the theory of integration can deal with non-continuous $n$-forms (but I might be wrong).
If the answer is yes : we obtain a function from the Borel sets of $M$ to $\mathbb{C}$, $\mu_\omega : A\mapsto I_\omega(\chi_A)$. Is this a complex (Radon) measure ?
And more broadly, is there any reference that explains the link between integration over a $n$-form, and complex measures ? I have not yet seen the explicit link between those two.

I suppose all these follows from the Riesz representation theorem, since $I_\omega$ is a functional on $C(M)$.
